# Memory leak caused by a wrong usage of scoped_lock?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, scoped-lock

I have a memory leak, and I guess it's caused by a wrong usage of scoped_lock (Boost). I however don't manage to find the exact problem, and I do believe that the way the code has been written is not completely right neither.

The code is in this class there:
http://taf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/31767#511225

The main important method is ThreadedLoop(). Basically, this method is started within a thread, and checks regularly for market data to be downloaded for Yahoo. For each stock (or else), a new thread will be created (for the ExecuteNextRequest() method), passing as a parameter a pointer to  string containing the stock name. This is the only memory allocation I do, but it's released at the end of the thread execution.

I would be also interested in how this code could be enhanced (of course I could use a threadpool, but that's not the point yet). Many thanks!

Comment: misuse of a locking primitive will more likely cause deadlocks, not memory leaks

Comment: You could just use a simple `std::string` instead of a pointer to it. I don't think the pointer serves any purpose, but I also don't think it's the reason for your memory leak...

Comment: @sth: I agree with your comment. However, in cases where one might want to use the string to be mutable, and have changes visible to all references that see it, then a `shared_ptr` is still useful. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that, instead of using a "raw" pointer to `std::string`, you use a `boost::shared_ptr<std::string>`, and pass that around. When you're done, call its `reset()` function; it will decrement the usage count, and free the string automatically when the count is 0.

As a bonus, you can attach `boost::weak_ptr` objects to those strings (you can stick them into a `vector` maybe), and monitor how many of them are still "live". This way you'll know if something's causing the strings to not be decremented to 0 for any reason.

To be clear:

```
if (_tickersQueue.size() > 0)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> ticker(new std::string(PopNextTicker()));
    if (!ticker->empty())
        _threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&TAFYahooFinanceParadigm::ExecuteNextRequest, this, ticker));
    else
        ticker.reset();  // optional; ticker will drop out of scope anyway
}
```

Yes, you have to adjust the function type of `ExecuteNextRequest` appropriately. :-)

Comment: You right, using a raw pointer here was useless. However, the memory leak was related to the intensive creations of threads... I implemented a minimalist thread pool and it works a lot better.